# Why colors of 'angular-tag-cloud-module' are not working?

Tags: angular7, word-cloud

I used the `angular-tag-cloud-module` library to plot a word cloud in Angular, but I had always words colored with blue (default color).
Could you help me to change it ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module

I tried the same code written here:

```js
data: CloudData[] = [
    {text: 'Weight-8-link-color', weight: 8, link: 'https://google.com', color: '#ffaaee'},
    {text: 'Weight-10-link', weight: 10, link: 'https://google.com', tooltip: 'display a tooltip'},

  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the words are blue is because anchor tags (`<a></a>`) are blue by default.
Use this to reset the  tag default color:

```css
a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the link value , it's making the link blue